# Assigning value based on if cell is inbetween external tuple values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas series of integer values and a dictionary of keys and tuples (2 integers).

The tuples represent a high low value for each key. I'd like to map the key value to each cell of my series based on which tuple the series value falls into.

Example:

`d = {'a': (1,5), 'b': (6,10), 'c': (11,15)}` keys and tuples are ordered and never repeated

`s = pd.Series([5, 6, 5, 8, 15, 5, 2, 5])`: I can sort series and there can be multiple repeated or not present values

for a shorter list i can do this manually i believe with a for loop but I can potentially have big dictionary with many keys.

Comment: Are the tuples always contiguous or could there be a gap between some, i.e. 'd': (18, 20)? Also are the values always integers? What happens if S were 5.5?

Comment: values of s and tuples in d will always be integers. the tuples are generally continuous but not necessarily always there could be a gap. i.e. `{... 'd': (20,25)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `pd.Interval`:

```
lookup = pd.Series(list(d.keys()), 
                   index=[pd.Interval(x,y, closed='both') for x,y in d.values()])

lookup.loc[s]
```

Output:

```
[1, 5]      a
[6, 10]     b
[1, 5]      a
[6, 10]     b
[11, 15]    c
[1, 5]      a
[1, 5]      a
[1, 5]      a
dtype: object
```

`reindex` also works and safer in the case you have out-of-range data:

```
lookup.reindex(s)
```

Output:

```
5     a
6     b
5     a
8     b
15    c
5     a
2     a
5     a
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea using [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m = pd.Series(list(d.keys()), 
       index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(d.values(), closed='both'))
s = s.map(m)
```

Result:

```
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    b
4    c
5    a
6    a
7    a
dtype: object
```